# How can I change the image folder name in css files dynamically?

Tags: php, css

My project is in PHP, I need change the image folder name in css files dynamically,

ie.,

```
# all.css file

.html{
background: url(../img/login.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 -36px;
.....
}
```

I need change the folder name "img" to "image" or "styleimg" etc., depends on the templatewise. How is it possible with the php file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = xyz.css;
$handle = @fopen($file, "r"); // Open file form read.

$line_match = "background: url(../img/login.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 -36px;\n";

$toThis = "background: url(../img/new_login_image.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 -36px;\n";

if ($handle) {
while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
{
$buffer .= fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
if ($buffer == $line_match) // Check for string.
{
echo "$buffer"; // If not string show contents.
} else {
$buffer .= $toThis; // If string, change it.
echo "$buffer"; // and show changed contents.
}
}

$Handle = fopen($file, 'w');
$Data = $buffer; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 


fclose($handle); // Close the file.
}

?>
```

maybe drop the \n im from vars $linematch and $toThis not sure off hand! - try both.

Comment: Hi cocacola09, This will rewrite the css file. I need change the image folder name dynamically (by ussing variable or any other method ), depends on the member choose red,green or etc template color. 100 more members are login at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP to serve out the CSS. Use the header() to set the content type as text/css, output most of the CSS outside of the  tag (but after setting the header of course). Find out the selected template in this PHP, assign the required directory name to a variable, say, $imgloc.

Then, at the lines where you require to output the image name, do something like this:

```
background: url(../<?= $imgloc ?>/login.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 -36px;
```

Comment: Raze, we need do to with external stylesheet only.